# An expression of non-boolean expression in dynamic sql concatenated string

Tags: sql, dynamic, exec, concatenation, conditional-statements

```
declare @SqlString nvarchar(max);
declare @tmpTable nvarchar(50) = '#tmpTable', @tmpColumn nvarchar(50) = 'Name'
declare @ConcatString nvarchar(max);

set @SqlString = N'Create Table ' + @tmpTable + '(' + @tmpColumn + ' nvarchar(255));
'
+ ' 
while(select top(1) ' + @tmpColumn + ' from ' + @tmpTable + ') 
begin

if(ISNULL(@ConcatString, 0) = 0)
    begin 
        set @ConcatString += (select top(1) ' + @tmpColumn + ' from ' + @tmpTable +') ' + '
    end 
else
    begin 
        set @ConcatString += '','' + (select top(1) ' + @tmpColumn + ' from ' + @tmpTable +') 
    end 
end'

--print @SqlString
EXEC sp_executesql @SqlString, N'@ConcatString nvarchar(max)', @ConcatString = 0
select @ConcatString as ConcatString
```

---

Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'begin'.

Comment: i don't know why SQL considers the following statement not including a boolean expression:

if(ISNULL(@ConcatString, 0) = 0)

Comment: `while` expects a boolean condition, whereas you specify `select` in your query

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get the point, i selected the boolean expression but the issue still occurs, so i would be so appreciated if you explained in more detail with an example.

thanks in advance